# Solving lonely int using map in c++

Tags: c++, maps

Given an array of integers, where all elements but one occur twice, find the unique element.

Example: Where `a = {1,2,3,4,3,2,1}`, the unique element is `4`.

I realize using an XOR operation is the way to go with solving this problem but I thought it interesting to solve it using a map; however, I'm having a problem when the inputs are double digits: the answer defaults to null.

My code:

```cpp
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    vector<int> a = {34, 95, 34, 64, 45, 95, 16, 80, 80, 75, 3, 25, 75, 25, 31, 3, 64, 16, 31};
    
    //vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int lone_int = 0;
    map<int, int> int_freq; 
    for(int i = 0;i<a.size();i++){
        int key = a[i];
        int_freq[key] = int_freq[key] + 1;
    }
    
    for(const auto &x: int_freq){
        if(x.second == 1)lone_int = x.first;
        else lone_int = '/0';
        cout << x.first << " "  << x.second << endl;
    }
    cout << lone_int << endl;
}
```

Comment: The `else`-part is the problem, because it will overwrite the value you have already found. Just remove it,

Comment: `'/0'` is wrong. Just remove the `else` part of the loop and you're fine. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/eszcEfPvf)

Comment: Owner of a lonely `int`. Much better than a owner of a broken `int`.

Comment: @user4581301 I "heard" you say that in the voice of Jon Anderson.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the `else lone_int = '/0';` line. First, if you are trying to assign a null character to `lone_int`, then you need a **backslash** (`\`), rather than the *forward* slash, before the `0`. As it is, you are assigning a multi-character literal value to an `int` variable, which happens to have the value of `12080` on my Windows/MSVC system. Also, there's no point assigning such a literal (`nul`) character to an `int` – that has exactly the same effect as a simple `lone_int = 0;` statement.

Second, you shouldn't have that line in your code **at all**. Once you have found the unique integer, you can just skip out of the loop; or, if you do want to print the remaining entries with their counts, just continue the iterations of the loop normally.

With that line present, your code will only work if the unique integer is the last entry in the map; otherwise, it will be reset (to zero, if you fix the backslash) on the very next run through the loop. (Note that, in your commented-out, single-digit example vector, the unique integer *will* be the last entry in the map, because it also happens to be the *largest* integer in the vector.)

Comment: Re: "the value of `12080` -- the value of a multicharacter literal, if the implementation supports them, is implementation defined.